# Dynamically control jQuery Mobile events/actions

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamiclly controll the action of the JQuery mobile swipeleft & swiperight events but Jquery Mobile seems to append instructions. Ex:

```
function student_control(stat){
if (stat==true){
    $("#pageholder").swipeleft(function(e) {
        previousPage();
    });

    $("#pageholder").swiperight(function(e) {
        nextPage();
    });
}
else{
    $("#pageholder").swipeleft(function(e) {console.log('disabled');});

    $("#pageholder").swiperight(function(e) {console.log('disabled');});
}
}
```

If in the first call the stat was true & then in the second call it was false, function will log "disabled" and will also change the page (if the function is recalled it goes 2 pages forward/back ect)
It means JQuery Mobile stores all the instructions given inside `function(){}` and does not rewrite them.

Is there any way to rewrite them?

Comment: use `.on('swipeleft swiperight', fucntion()`

Comment: I have tried using .on, but still the same problem.

Comment: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gVfSJ/

Comment: This one works correctly. Thats how i have done that. 

    `$("#pageholder").swipeleft(function(e) {
       if(st_control == true){
          previousPage();
       } 
    });`

But i was just asking if is there any way to reset the actions (callbacks) of an jquery event.

Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found it. Unbind-ing and rebind-ing it works ...

Disable

```
$("#pageholder").unbind('swipeleft');
$("#pageholder").unbind('swiperight');
```

Enable

```
$("#pageholder").bind('swipeleft', function (){
//do something here
});
$("#pageholder").bind('swiperight', function (){
//do something here
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/domeri/jMpMw/1/